# .html() vs .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a text editor. When the user double-clicks on a specific `<div>`, the `contentEditable` property is set to `true` and some editor tools appear. Then, the user can choose between clicking on "save" and "escape". If he escapes, I want to restore the previous data in this `<div>`. So I copy data on first double-click (`temp['htmlTxt']`) and then:

```
$('#esc').click(function() {
    var confEsc = confirm('---\n\nSouhaitez-vous quitter sans enregistrer vos modifications ?\n\n---');

    if(confEsc) { 

       //Do you know why that works :
       var id = document.getElementById(temp['myId']);
       id.innerHTML = temp['htmlTxt'];

       //and why that doesn't work ?
       $('#'+temp['myId']).html(temp['htmlTxt'])
    }
});
```

I don't understand why it works fine with classic JavaScript and not with jQuery...

Comment: What is `temp['htmlTxt']` equal to?

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle? Meanwhile, what is the value of `temp['htmlTxt']` ?

Comment: can you show your html as well?

Comment: What exactly occurs when using the JQuery? Does it set it to blank? Not change it at all? Kick your puppy?

Comment: Do you get any error messages in chrome console or firebug? I can't see anything wrong to be honest

Comment: what `temp['htmlTxt']` contains?? will u please provide basic HTML too

Comment: Source of `$.fn.html`: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L210-249

Comment: how did you obtain 'temp['htmlTxt']'?

Comment: here jsfiddle sample (but it works...) I have the same structure in my project, but with more complexes datas. http://jsfiddle.net/deee9/5/

Comment: for me, it return a empty string.. no error message on firebug

Comment: other detail, my original text is generated by a php loop with sql request to my DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those 2 are practically identical. However jQuery does some pre-processing that might be getting in your way...

**jQuery Globals**

```
rnoInnerHtml = /<(?:script|style)/i;
rtagName = /<([\w:]+)/;
rleadingWhitespace = /^\s+/;
rxhtmlTag = /<(?!area|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param)(([\w:]+)[^>]*)\/>/gi;
wrapMap = {
    "option": [1, "<select multiple='multiple'>", "</select>"],
    "legend": [1, "<fieldset>", "</fieldset>"],
    "thead": [1, "<table>", "</table>"],
    "tr": [2, "<table><tbody>", "</tbody></table>"],
    "td": [3, "<table><tbody><tr>", "</tr></tbody></table>"],
    "col": [2, "<table><tbody></tbody><colgroup>", "</colgroup></table>"],
    "area": [1, "<map>", "</map>"],
    "_default": [0, "", ""],
    "optgroup": [1, "<select multiple='multiple'>", "</select>"],
    "caption": [1, "<table>", "</table>"],
    "colgroup": [1, "<table>", "</table>"],
    "tfoot": [1, "<table>", "</table>"],
    "tbody": [1, "<table>", "</table>"],
    "th": [3, "<table><tbody><tr>", "</tr></tbody></table>"]
};
```

**.html(value) setter**

```
var elem = this[0] || {},
    i = 0,
    l = this.length;

if (typeof value === "string" && !rnoInnerhtml.test(value) && 
    (jQuery.support.leadingWhitespace || !rleadingWhitespace.test(value)) && 
    !wrapMap[(rtagName.exec(value) || ["", ""])[1].toLowerCase()]) {

    value = value.replace(rxhtmlTag, "<$1></$2>");

    try {
        for (; i < l; i++) {
            // Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
            elem = this[i] || {};
            if (elem.nodeType === 1) {
                jQuery.cleanData(elem.getElementsByTagName("*"));
                elem.innerHTML = value;
            }
        }

        elem = 0;

        // If using innerHTML throws an exception, use the fallback method
    } catch(e) {}
}

if (elem) {
    this.empty().append(value);
}
```

that's straight out of the current version for the setter on `.html(string)`

so basically if you `value` (1) isn't a string, (2) has a script tag, (3) your on a browser that doesn't support leading white-space and you string isn't trimmed, (4) you tag falls into the `wrapMap` special use cases OR (5) innerHTML fails for ANY other reason..  THEN you are essentially calling `.empty().append(value)` which is a whole different ball of wax... -ck

Answer (score 1):

It depends wholly on the contents of temp['htmlTxt'] I would think. I have seen people trying to inject javascript onto the page (as a tag like `<script type="text/javascript"><script>`) using .html() but jQuery strips this out.

But on a side, and probably unpopular note, the DOM is not a string. innerHTML is prone to leaking across older browsers. Consider using a different property than .innerHTML